# Store and Query Posts in Firestore in a performant way

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

So I need to store Posts that are created by Users, now the data modell is the problem, bringing all existing Posts in a Posts Collection with a field of creatorUserID will make it able to show posts belonging to a user.

Now a User has a Subcollection called Followers with the ID of people following, the problem with that is that Im not sure how a query would look to show only Posts of People that the User follows.

Also im worried about performance when there are 10mio+ Posts in the collection.

Comment: Instead of describing the database structure please add a screenshot of it and indicate the records that you want to get.

Comment: @AlexMamo the structure doesnt exist yet the question is what the most efficient structure would be for such a purpose

Comment: It would be fairly straightforward to read in the uid's stored in the users following collection and then iterate over them to query the posts node for posts containing their user uid's. Also this is a logical OR query and from the docs *Logical OR queries. In this case, you should create a separate query for each OR condition and merge the query results in your app.*

Answer (score 1):

In order to query a document in Firestore the data you want to query by needs to be on the Document you want to query, there is no way of querying a collection by the data of a document from another collection. This is why your use-case is a bit tricky. It might not seem very elegant, but this is a way of solving it:

We use two collections, users and posts.

```
User
    - email: string
    - followingUserIDs: array with docIds of users you are following

Posts
    - postName: string
    - postText: string
    - creatorUserID: string
```

To find all the posts belonging to all the users the logged in user is following, we can do the following in the code:

1 Retrieve the logged in user document

2 For each id in the "followingUserIDs" array I would query Firestore for the Posts. In JavaScript it would be something like:

```
followingUserIDs.map(followingUserId => {
        return firestore.collection('Posts', ref => ref.where('creatorUserID', 
        '==', followingUserId));
    })
```

3 Combine the result from all the queries into one array of posts

Comment: But wouldnt this be slow on bigger Amounts of a) following ppl and b) amount of posts in the posts collection?

Comment: Not really because in Firestore query performance is proportional to the size of your result set, not your data set.